# D3Cloud - send image base64 encoded to server

Tags: javascript, svg, base64, tag-cloud, word-cloud

maybe it's a silly question, but I wasn't able to figure it out by myself and I haven't found an approriate answer yet.

I'm building a website and I need to dynamically create tag-clouds from user inputs and store the resulting images on the webserver.

I'm creating the tagclouds with the d3cloud-library (https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud).

This is the div, where the tagcloud will be displayed and the draw function:

```
    <div id="cloud"></div>
...
    function draw(words) {
            d3.select("#cloud")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 850)
                .attr("height", 350)
                .attr("class", "wordcloud")
                .append("g")
                // without the transform, words words would get cutoff to the left and top, they would
                // appear outside of the SVG area
                .attr("transform", "translate(320,200)")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(words)
                .enter().append("text")
                .style("font-size", function(d) { 
                    return d.size + "px"; 
                })
                .style("fill", function(d, i) { 
                    return color(i);
                     })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                })
                .text(function(d) { 
                    return d.text; 
                });
```

Is it possible to encode the resulting tag-cloud-image with base64 and store it into a variable? I need to send it to a server in a later step. I know how the sending part works, my problem is just to get the encoded image-data.

regards

Comment: can you use `canvas` instead of `div`? see this --> [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: XMLSerializer will turn a DOM into a string, then just base64 convert that string and you're done.